# How do you list all object with the same foreign key object?

Tags: python, django

I have a Department model with a name field, then User model with department field using foreignkey to Department. How can I list in a template all users in a Department? Is there a way without using many to many?

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64,unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class User(AbstractUser):
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    blank=True,null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

Answer (score 0):

`User.objects.filter(department=<dept>)`  This would filter the details based on the department.

Comment: Thank you, so on the DepartmentDetail view what would be the most efficient code to achieve this?

Comment: Can I see your current department details view?

Comment: class DepartmentDetail(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
        model = Department
        template_name = 'users/department_detail.html'
        ordering = ['name']

Comment: Except for a view class, you can proceed with a simple view function, and add a decorator for `login required`, in that case within the view you can.

```
user = User.objects.filter(department=<dept>)
return HttpResponse(content=json.dumps(user), content_type="application/json", status=200)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create a brand new queryset as long as you have a reference to the department you want to get users for.

Using this `models.py` for testing...

```
from django.db import models


class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class User(models.Model):
    username = models.TextField()
    department = models.ForeignKey(
        Department,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

This query should be identical to the one you'd need to retrieve users for a `Department` instance named `department`:

```
department.user_set.all()
```

Example from the Django shell:

```
>>> from depts.models import Department, User
>>> 
>>> department = Department.objects.create(name='The North Pole')
>>> 
>>> for name in ('kungphu', 'K. Jones', 'S. Claus'):
...     User.objects.create(
...         username=name,
...         department=department,
...     )
... 
<User: kungphu>
<User: K. Jones>
<User: S. Claus>
>>> for user in department.user_set.all():
...     print(user)
... 
kungphu
K. Jones
S. Claus
```

Also, you can use `department.users` instead of `department.user_set` if you add `related_name='users'` to the field `User.department`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So in the department detail view and template what would you do?

Comment: You're welcome. In a `DetailView` template, if you set [`context_object_name = 'department'`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#making-friendly-template-contexts), you can iterate over `department.user_set.all` with a [`for` loop](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for).